# Button Function Unavaiable in Unity

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I made some edit to Snake&Ladder game where a question pop-up when player reach head of snake or bottom of the ladder. I manage to get the pop-up question appear but I can't find the function, not even the able to search the function.

[image: Visual Studio snapshot showing that the button function is unavailable]

I put the button code under transform position code when the player move after reach head of snake or bottom of the ladder.

Am I not allowed to separate button code from other button code in Unity?

Comment: The runtime object in your screenshot says "None". Did you try dragging the relevant GameObject in there?

Comment: Oh god. I see why I'm unable to put any function there. Thank you for answering.

Comment: @Boss2Topp - Do you still need help, or can this question be closed as not reproducible?

Comment: It's done. Thank you. But I don't know yet how to close question.

Answer (score 0):

How to make a button invalid or hide when the program runs to a certain step.

method 1:

Command1.Enabled = False button command is disabled.

Command1.Visible = False button command hidden.

Method 2:

//disable

this.GetComponent().enabled= false;

//disable and gray

this.GetComponent().interactable = false;

Hope it helps you.